# Speeding up the weylus when connecting to Windows

Tags: tablet

[Weylus](https://github.com/H-M-H/Weylus) is an interesting opensource project which turns your tablet into a drawing pad, while mirroring the screen to the tablet. I use it to write in a windows environment, but there is slight latency when using it. My question is how can I further reduce the latency? I'm guessing there should be some optimized configuration or way, for instance, lowering the mirroring resolution, using USB, or other special configurations.

Comment: Well... have you tried USB / lower res? I haven't used this, but if you don't get an answer here, you could always go straight to the horses mouth (i.e. raise an issue on github).

Comment: How does it communicate between the tablet and PC? I'd guess over the network? USB on Android has a limited set of protocols it can use and probably won't work for direct communication for this tool.